# Backport railtie console change from Rails 4 to Rails 3.2.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, backport

I'm getting some annoying test-related warnings and deprecation notices when running `rails c` or `rails s`; I tracked it down to [this file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6591a10b1f6eccc91bc01ab708050884058e9665/railties/lib/rails/console_app.rb).

However, it looks like this issue is already fixed in Rails 4.x:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/686f94e
- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4c8fba1

But my company is not ready to upgrade to Rails 4.x quite yet.

How can I cleanly get these changes in 3.2.11?